# Executed failed threads again

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

So I have have script that uses about 50k threads, but only runs 10 at a time. I use the threading library for this and BoundedSemaphore to limit the threads to 10 at a time. In some cases there is not enough memory for all threads, but it is important that all threads get processed so I would like to repeat those threads that got killed because of insufficient memory.

```
import some_other_script, threading


class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, item):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.item = item
    def run(self):
        threadLimiter.acquire()
        some_other_script.method(self.item)
        somelist.remove(self.item)
        threadLimiter.release()


threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(10)

somelist = ['50,000 Items','.....]
for item in somelist:
    myThread(item).start()
```

As you can see the only idea I could come up with so far was to delete the item that got processed from the list within every thread with `somelist.remove(self.item)`. (Each item is unique and only present once within the list). 
My idea was that I could run a while loop around the for loop, to check if it still contains items, which did not work, because after the for loop is finished the threads are not finished an so the list isn't empty.
What I want to do is to catch those which fail, because the systems runs out of memory and executed them again (and again if need be).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: So what's wrong with your idea with the ```while``` loop?  Are you asking how to implement it? Alternatives? Code review?

Comment: Why not create the threads dynamically (only when they are needed)?. This approach is madness!

Answer (score 1):

This solves both the too many active threads problem and the problem in your question:

```
    def get_items():
          threads = threading.enumerate()
          items = set()
          for thr in threads:
              if isinstance(thr, myThread): items.add(thr.item)
          return items
    def manageThreads(howmany):
         while bigset:
             items = get_items()
             items_to_add = bigset.difference(items)
             while len(items) < howmany:
                 item = items_to_add.pop()
                 processor = myThread(item)
                 processor.start()
             with thread_done:    
                 thread_done.wait()
   thread_done = threading.Condition()
   bigset = set(["50,000 items", "..."])
   manageThreads(10)
```

The mythread class run method:

```
def run(self):
    try:
        some_other_script.method(self.item)
        bigset.remove(self.item)
    finally:
        with thread_done:
            thread_done.notify()
```

`Threading.enumerate()` returns a list of currently active thread objects. So, the manageThreads function initially creates 10 threads, then waits for one to finish, then checks the thread count again, and so on. If a thread runs out of memory or another error occurs during processing, it wont remove the item from the `bigset`, causing it to be requeued by the manager onto a different thread.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! What I can't see at the moment is how I hand over just one `item` of my `biglist` at a time to a thread?

Comment: Good point. I forgot to add the code to get an item. Are all the items in `biglist` unique? Does the order they are processed in matter?

Comment: yes every item is uniq in the form of aaa, aab, aac, aba, aca, bba, bca, ... etc and no the order does not matter