# Parallelization with highly unreliable workers?

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Suppose I've got a pool of workers (computers), around 1000 of them, but they're highly unreliable. I expect each to go down multiple times a day, sometimes for extended periods of time. Fyi these are volunteer computers running BOINC (not my botnet, I swear!)

Are there any tools that exist to facilitate using them to do parallel computations, (mostly trivially parallelizable)? I'm thinking something like an IPython parallel where maybe when a node dies the calculation is restarted elsewhere, and maybe where when a new node joins its brought up to speed to the current working environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [executing failed threads again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272897/executed-failed-threads-again)

Comment: I think my question is more general, if this tool exists it likely takes care of networking, replicating the environment, etc... and I'm not at all tied to Python, I'm just curious what's out there.